# Value of one range input changes only if other does

Tags: javascript, html

I want to update the value of range type input. I tried to do it like this:

```
let ranges = document.getElementsByClassName('range');
    
    for (let y = 1; y<ranges.length; y++) {
        ranges[y].addEventListener('change',function() {
            this.setAttribute('value',this.value);
        });
    }
```

I have 5 range type inputs. The first one changes only if i change the rest of them. This code is inside a function which is triggered whenever anything with input tag changes by using `onchange` tag attribute, so i thought it should update all the values even when i change only the first one range input.

I would really appreciate some help. Thanks in advance :).

Comment: `for (let y = 0; y<ranges.length; y++)`

Arrays start at 0